# Why does oAuth need access tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, acl

Platforms have users with a userId, and the external app can also be represented as a user with a userId. Just as users can grant other users access (read, write etc) to their resources, they can do that with apps, too.

So why can’t an external app simply authenticate its requests with the platform, by using its own userId (API key) and HMAC with the app’s own secret (or sign each request with its private key)? The user can manage permissions / scopes of the “oAuth” app by visiting the same control panel they would by granting any other user access.

What advantage does oAuth have by having this access token? The only advantage I see with access tokens or JWTs is that you can skip the I/O request to the authorization server, like using capabilities rather than Access Control Lists. But isn’t this just less secure — and anyway if you have to check access token revocations, you still have to do the same amount of I/O.

Basically I’m asking why can’t oAuth apps simply skip the access tokens since the platform knows what app is requesting what resource anyway?

Answer (score 2):

In `authorization_code` flow, it is the *user* that grants a 3rd party access to *their* information.

The client acts on *behalf* of the user, not itself.

Imagine you're using a desktop application or web application that directly talks to an API. If the credentials in the desktop application would be valid for *every user* that has granted access to to client, it would be a major issue.

For example, I use Thunderbird and it uses OAuth2 to authenticate with gmail. Gmail sends back an access token that limits Thunderbird to only access *my* email and not every other email account that has ever given access.

Comment: Well, for server applications, the difference seems to be mostly academic / semantics. The server can store all the tokens for all users in one place, so it “acts as itself” anyway, the question is whether a user has allowed it with an ACL (rather than given a capability like a JWT).. However I see your point for desktop applications, to be sure. To handle that, each instance would probably be considered a different “user” on the platform. I  can see how this might create too many lightweight “users”, OTOH hand this would allow the desktop apps to network together to carry out tasks as agents.

Comment: @GregMagarshak idk if there's a question here. Sounds like you just want to go on a rant? A blog might be a more appropreiate place for that

Comment: The question is why the design of oAuth needed the tokens, basically. I asked in the past why shared secrets were used instead of asymmetric keys. The question is im that vein

Comment: Yes and I gave you some reasons why they are used. It allows the secrets to be used in contexts where the resource owner has access to them.

Comment: I even upvoted your answer.